# Get average of previous n records based on dates from a second data frame

Tags: r

I have two dataframes the first is just a column of dates between two dates;

```
 dates <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2006-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = 'days'))
```

The second is an average value £ of sales for given dates but there are not entries for all days. For each date in the dates dataframe I'd like to get an average of the 7 records in df2 before (or including) that date.

```
Date <- sample(seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by="day"),replace=F, 2000)
Value <- runif(2000, min=0, max=2)
df2 <- data.frame(Date,Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an approach using `slider` and `dplyr`. You can merge your dataframes `dates` and `df2` and then computing the rolling average each seven days. In slider that can be done setting the value of six in the function `slide_dbl()`. Here the code:

```
library(slider)
library(dplyr)
#Pipeline
names(dates)[1] <- 'Date'
#Join
df3 <- dates %>% left_join(df2)
#Use slider functions
df4 <- df3 %>% 
  mutate(rollingAvg = slide_dbl(Value, mean,na.rm=T, .before = 6, .complete = T))
```

Output (some rows):

```
head(df4,10)
         Date     Value rollingAvg
1  2006-01-01 1.5529632         NA
2  2006-01-02        NA         NA
3  2006-01-03        NA         NA
4  2006-01-04 1.3981900         NA
5  2006-01-05 1.7578603         NA
6  2006-01-06        NA         NA
7  2006-01-07 0.2430505   1.238016
8  2006-01-08 1.7651115   1.291053
9  2006-01-09 1.9900415   1.430851
10 2006-01-10        NA   1.430851
```

**Update:** Based on comment I include a loop solution. This code must be used after merging the two dataframes. Here the code. We create an index `i1` for those positions which are not `NA` and then in the loop we make some controls to compute the mean of only the last non `NA` values:

```
#Detech non NA positions after merge
i1 <- which(!is.na(df3$Value))
#Create empty var
df3$NewVar <- NA
#Loop
for(q in i1)
{
  #First build a vector to extract values for mean
  v1 <- df3$Value[1:q]
  #Check for 7 non na
  v2 <- length(which(!is.na(v1)))
  #Conditional
  if(v2>=7)
  {
    #Filter non na values
    v3 <- v1[!is.na(v1)]
    #Choose last 7 values
    v4 <- v3[(length(v3)-6):length(v3)]
    #Compute mean
    vmean <- mean(v4)
  } else
  {
    vmean <- NA
  }
  #Assign
  df3$NewVar[q] <- vmean
}
```

Output (some rows):

```
head(df3,15)
         Date     Value   NewVar
1  2006-01-01 1.5529632       NA
2  2006-01-02        NA       NA
3  2006-01-03        NA       NA
4  2006-01-04 1.3981900       NA
5  2006-01-05 1.7578603       NA
6  2006-01-06        NA       NA
7  2006-01-07 0.2430505       NA
8  2006-01-08 1.7651115       NA
9  2006-01-09 1.9900415       NA
10 2006-01-10        NA       NA
11 2006-01-11 0.5249755 1.318885
12 2006-01-12        NA       NA
13 2006-01-13 1.9514706 1.375814
14 2006-01-14 0.6119763 1.263498
15 2006-01-15 0.8507210 1.133907
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question but i would like to average the previous 7 non NA values rather than the previous 7 rows, so i'd like to jump NA records. For example in the output rows you have there the rollingAvg would all be NA as there isn't 7 non NA values for Value.

Comment: @helen.h Hi Helen. I have added an update based on the logic you mentioned in the comment. It is based on loop. I hope that can be helpful.